# htaccess rewriterule preserve post data

Tags: .htaccess

The address of the contact form of my website is

www.mysite.com/contact

and the actual contact form address is www.mysite.com/contact.php

When the user fills the contact form, i want contact.php to receive the post data coming from "/contact". I created a folder named contact and put a .htaccess file with the content below

```
RewriteRule (.*) /contact.php
```

But the post data is lost after the form is submitted and /contact is redirected to contact.php. Any ideas to solve it?

Comment: Are you putting `contact.php` as the form action or `/contact`?

Comment: /contact. Because I want visitors to see www.mysite.com/contact on the address line after from submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `contact` directory.
2. Put this rule in the htaccess file in your *document root*

   ```
   RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /contact.php [L]
   ```

The reason why you are losing your POST data and getting redirected is because if there is a `contact` directory, and you request `/contact`, the mod_dir module will redirect you to `/contact/` to enforce trailing slashes for requests to directories. The redirect and the rewrite both get applied and thus you see `/contact.php`.